# How to force List to redraw by another View's toggle Button?

Tags: list, swiftui, toggle

I fetched JSON data from Google Sheet and populate into a List using ForEach. I used struct HeaderView located in another View and place a Button to serve as a toggle. However, the List will not redraw when I press the toggle button even I use @State ascd variable.

Below is some of my code, is there anything I miss?

```
struct HeaderView: View {
    // @State var asc: Bool = true
    var holding: String = "持倉"
    var earning: String = "賺蝕"
    // @State var tog_value: Bool = ContentView().ascd

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                ContentView().ascd.toggle()
            }
            ) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            Text(holding)
            Text(earning)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var viewModelTotal = ContentViewModelTotal()
    @State var ascd: Bool = false
    var totalss = ContentViewModelTotal.fetchDatasTotal
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: HeaderView()) {
                ForEach(viewModel.rows, id: \.stockname) { rows in
                    // Text(user.stock_name)
                    ListRow(name: rows.stockname, code: rows.stockcode, cur_price: rows.currentprice, mkt_value: rows.marketvalue, amnt: rows.amount, avg_cost: rows.averagecost, pft: rows.profit, pft_pcnt: rows.profitpercent)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.fetchDatas()
                self.ascd.toggle()
                if self.ascd {
                    self.viewModel.rows.sort { $0.stockname < $1.stockname }
                } else {
                    self.viewModel.rows.sort { $0.stockname > $1.stockname }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just change the model belonging to that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing another View's variable you can use a `@Binding` variable:

```
struct HeaderView: View {
    ...

    @Binding var ascd: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.ascd.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            Text(holding)
            Text(earning)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend moving sorting logic to your `ViewModel`.

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ascd: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if ascd {
                rows.sort { $0.hashValue < $1.hashValue }
            } else {
                rows.sort { $0.hashValue > $1.hashValue }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

If it's in the `.onAppear` in the `ContentView` it will be executed only when your `View` is shown on the screen.

And you will have to initialise your `HeaderView` with your ViewModel's `ascd` variable:

```
HeaderView(ascd: $viewModel.ascd)
```